# How do I identify a submitted field in a Drupal 6 webform?

Tags: php, drupal, webforms

I am trying to add code to the Drupal 6 confirmation page that gets sent when someone submits a Webform. I have a place to add confirmation page HTML or plain text messages, but I would like to personalize it based on information submitted in the Webform.

I am imagining something like a PHP line that echoes the right field.

```php
$name = $_SESSION[submitted][webform][first_name][0];
echo $name;
```

I tried different ways and nothing seems to work. I looked at
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/programmatically-get-webform-submitted-field-values and http://www.drupal.org/node/139629.

If anyone knows how to pull a field out of a submitted form, that'd be great to know.

(I have also tried using "%value[first_name]" and that returns only the words %value[first_name] as the output.)